# Integer to string with given radix

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest function to convert an integer into a numeric representation given a radix between 2 and 62. e.g.:

```
to_string(351837066319, 31) => "codegolf"
```

Comment: From the example I gather that lower case letters come first, i.e. the digits in base 62 are 0-9,a-z,A-Z in that order?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's it.

Comment: `at 0:00`, dang, perfect.

Comment: @Adalynn posted at _46 seconds_ after midnight (Zulu), so not _that_ perfect.

Answer (score 5):

## Python - 86

```py
from string import*
def t(n,r,s=''):
 while n:s=printable[n%r]+s;n/=r
 return s or'0'
```

Credit due to Hoa Long Tam for the string import trick

Answer (score 4):

### dc - 43 chars

```
[sb[58-]s_[lb~dZ39*+dB3<_9+rd0<xrP]dsxxk]sf
```

We can shorten this a little if we assume the stack contains only the two arguments.

```
[[58-]s_dSb~dZ39*+dB3<_9+SadLbr0<fLaPc]sf
```

As a standalone program, we only need 37 characters:

```
?o[58-]s_[O~dZ39*+dB3<_9+rd0<xrP]dsxx
```

Instead of using `[39+]sz9<z`, we simply use `Z39*+`, which will add 39 for a single digit number, and 78 for a double digit number. Instead of `113`, we use `B3` (`AD` also works).

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby 1.8 - 75 characters, with recursion.

```rb
f=proc{|n,b|(n<b ? "":f[n/b,b])+([*'0'..'9']+[*'a'..'z']+[*'A'..'Z'])[n%b]}
```

#### Without recursion

```rb
f=proc{|n,b|d=[*'0'..'9']+[*'a'..'z']+[*'A'..'Z'];s=d[n%b];s=d[n%b]+s while(n/=b)>0;s}
```

(both based on Dogbert's 1.9 solution.)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>93</s> 99

```py
from string import *
d=digits+letters
def t(n,b):
 s=''
 while n>0:s=d[n%b]+s;n/=b
 return s or '0'
```

**EDIT**: " or '0'" added for empty string case

Comment: Fails when n = 0, returns an empty string when it should return '0'. Anyway +1 for the string trick

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 1.9 - <strike>80</strike> <strike>74</strike> 68

```rb
t=->n,b{d=*?0..?9,*?a..?z,*?A..?Z;s='';(s=d[n%b]+s;n/=b)while n>0;s}
```

With '0' for empty string, <strike>95</strike> <strike>89</strike> 82 characters:

```rb
t=->n,b,s=''{d=*?0..?9,*?a..?z,*?A..?Z;(s=d[n%b]+s;n/=b)while n>0;s.empty?? ?0: s}
```

Ruby 1.9 - unfortunately only works up to base 36:

```rb
t=->n,b{n.to_s(b)}
```

Comment: You can replace the `]+[`'s with `,`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - <strike>72</strike> <strike>70</strike> 59 chars

```
f=->n,b{(n<b ? "":f[n/b,b])+[*?0..?9,*?a..?z,*?A..?Z][n%b]}
```

### Without recursion, 70 chars

```
f=->n,b{d=*?0..?9,*?a..?z,*?A..?Z;s=d[n%b];s=d[n%b]+s while(n/=b)>0;s}
```

Test

```
irb(main):080:0> f[351837066319, 31]
=> "codegolf"
irb(main):081:0> f[0, 31]
=> "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

## dc, 61 chars

```
[sr[lr~rd0<x]dsxxk[39+]sa[58-]sb[d9<ad78<b48+anz0<p]dspxIP]sf
```

Run as:

```
dc -e'[sr[lr~rd0<x]dsxxk[39+]sa[58-]sb[d9<ad78<b48+anz0<p]dspxIP]sf' -e'351837066319 31 lfx'
```

or:

```
dc -f base.dc -e '351837066319 31 lfx'
```

Explanation:
We take the number and base on the stack. `sr` saves the base in register r. The recursive function `[lr~rd0<x]dsxx` decomposes a number `TOS` into its digits in base `register r`. The first digit is always 0, removed from the stack by `k` (set precision, which by default is 0 also, so it's equivalent to a nop). Then, the recursive function `[48+d57<ad122<banz0<p]dspx` outputs each digit in ASCII, with the help of functions a (`[39+]sa`) and b (`[58-]sb`). `IP` outputs a newline. The function is stored in register `f`, and can be invoked by `lfx`.

Comment: If you move 48+ to the end it saves two (57 and 122 both drop a character). Also a minor oversight is that as a function, you can't assume there is nothing else on the stack, but the problem would be removed if you merged the loops (which would also save a few characters).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,b:n and f(n/b,b)+chr(n%b+48+(n%b>9)*39-n%b/36*58)or''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBDoMgEADAr3BpZAFjcZWCSfsXtoRooqshXvp6qqeZ43fOO/e15vcaN0pRsKGJReQksuSODIH@zkXyg/Tg9e0ngMLQXuvQqdHDXpqmHmXhU2aJo/X4ejqHNhi0APUP)

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 4 bytes

```
peB!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/INVJ8f9/Y1NDC2NzAzMzY0NLBWNDAA)

Luckily a built-in in Burlesque

```
pe # Parse and push
B! # Convert base
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 109 characters

```
m=divMod
d(0,x)b=[f x]
d(r,x)b=f x:d(m r b)b
f=(!!)$['0'..'9']++['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']
s x b=reverse$d(m x b)b
```

Comment: Feels a bit wrong suggesting golfs to something over 10 years old, but I may as well note that this [can be shaved down a good 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcdRDoIgGADgd0/xu7kBWUzHsmzR1gG6QOYDChYLzEFzrsNHWW/fdxP@rowJnl8CdmpUzitKqI0sx3K/OBAq9Xh6yEhCg7PlRHjVwVT/6uZ@t7PgoIk6juOYJBXKEKWoRHWaVkjMfv19nH1GdbBC98BhcLp/QgIe2Drfsk1WFCwvgeXh3XZGXH1YtcPwAQ), by factoring the whole `d(m r b)b` pattern into `m`  (with a bit of help from the `Applicative` instance for functions), then using that to convert `s` to pointfree.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 79 chars

```bsh
f(){
dc<<<$2o$1p|perl -pe"y/A-Z/a-z/;s/ \d+/chr$&+($&<10?48:$&<36?87:29)/ge"
}
```

Comment: BC_BASE_MAX is documented as being 16.  I don't know what miracle makes the output right on the sample input, but it outputs garbage (i.e. non alphanum characters) for most other bases.

Comment: @J B: which bc are you using? GNU bc should work. `sysconf(_SC_BC_BASE_MAX)` returns 99 on my system, 16 is the minimum required.

Comment: @J B: also note that previous revisions where buggy, I had just skimmed at the question requirements.

Comment: bc 1.06.  Now you mention it, I got the figure from the manpage, but misread it.  16 is the input base limit.  The output base limit is 999.  I did first try on an earlier version, let's see that again now.

Comment: @J B. forget what I said about 16 being the minimum required. POSIX requires 99 as a minimum (`_POSIX2_BC_BASE_MAX`). `BC_BASE_MAX` is the implementation-specific minimum, and `_SC_BC_BASE_MAX` is the runtime minimum. Actually, the `bc` `limits` statement outputs `BC_BASE_MAX = 2147483647` on my system.

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted but forgot to comment again. Sure enough, your latest version worked fine.  About limits, see my other comment: all's good.

Comment: I think this one outputs uppercase letters for bases 11-16 instead of lower case. You can save a few at the base conversion by using `dc` instead of `bc`.

Comment: @Nabb: Good catch. You also inspired me to do a pure `dc` version.

Answer (score 1):

### Befunge - 53 x 2 = 106 characters

Or 53 + 46 = 99 characters if you're willing to route other parts of your program through the bottom left.

```
11p01-\>:11g%\11g/:#v_$>:1+!#v_:45+`!#v_:75*`!#v_   v
       ^            <  ^,    $# +"0"  < +"'"   <-":"<
```

First place the number to be converted on the stack, then the radix and enter this function from the top-left going right.  Will output the string for you (since Befunge doesn't support string variables) and leave from the bottom `$` going down.  Requires the `(1,1)` cell for radix storage.

E.g. for the example given put `351837066319` into the input and run:

```
&56*1+    11p01-\>:11g%\11g/:#v_$>:1+!#v_:45+`!#v_:75*`!#v_   v
                 ^            <  ^,    $# +"0"  < +"'"   <-":"<
                                       @
```

Answer (score 1):

### Golfscript - 32 chars

```
{base{.9>39*+.74>58*48--}%''+}:f
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
b‘ịØB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/pUcOMh7u7D89w@v//v7GpoYWxuYGZmbGh5X9jQwA)

The case will be reversed (codegolf - CODEGOLF) because of Jelly built-in base characters string.

#### How?

```
b‘ịØB - Link, input x & y
b     - Convert x to base y
 ‘    - Increment (because Jelly use based-1 indexing)
  ị   - List (string) indexing
   ØB - "0-9 A-Z a-z"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](//golang.org), 76 bytes

```go
package m
import."math/big"
func e(n int64)string{return NewInt(n).Text(62)}
```

bonus decode:

```go
package m
import."math/big"
func d(s string)int64{o,_:=NewInt(0).SetString(s,62)
return o.Int64()}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Follows the example of the Jelly solution in reversing the casing.

```
;sVîEowi%
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O3NW7kVvd2kl&input=MzUxODM3MDY2MzE5CjMx)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
VL(:B
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VL%28%3AB&i=351837066319,+31)

Same size packed, a custom base conversion.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Minteger -ap`, 52 bytes

```perl
do{$\=(0..9,a..z,A..Z)[$_%$F[1]].$\}while$_/=$F[1]}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8lv1olxlbDQE/PUidRT69Kx1FPL0ozWiVeVcUt2jA2Vk8lprY8IzMnVSVe3xYsVFv9/7@xqaGFsbmBmZmxoaWCseG//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGQDozryQ1PbXov25iAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
вžLšRsè
```

-1 byte by switching to the legacy version of 05AB1E, where the switch_case builtin was one byte (it's `.š` in the new version).

Inputs in the order \$radix,number\$. Output as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//wqaj@3yOLgwqPrzi/39jQy5jU0MLY3MDMzNjQ0sA)

**Old 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) non-legacy 05AB1E answers (same I/O as above):**

- `žhži«£Åв` - [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX//8W@aMW@acKrwqPDhdCy//8zMQozNTE4MzcwNjYzMTk)
- `вžK9Ý†sè` - [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//wqaj@7wtD8991LCg@PCK//@NDbmMTQ0tjM0NzMyMDS0B)

**Explanation:**"

```python
в        # Convert the second (implicit) input to base-(first implicit input) as list
 žL      # Push string "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210"
   š     # Switch case: "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210"
    R    # Reverse it: "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
     s   # Swap so the list is at the top
      è  # Index each into this string
         # (after which the resulting character-list is output implicitly)
```

```python
žh       # Push constant string "0123456789"
    «    # Append
  ži     # Constant string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
         #  "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
     £   # Only keep the first (implicit) input amount of characters from this string
      Åв # Convert the second (implicit) input to this custom base-"0-9a-zA-Z"
         # (which basically converts it to base-length, and indexes it into the string)
         # (after which the resulting character-list is output implicitly)

в        # Convert the second (implicit) input to base-(first implicit input) as list
 žK      # Push string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012346789"
   9Ý    # Push list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
     †   # Filter all those characters to the front:
         #  "012346789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
      s  # Swap so the list is at the top
       è # Index each into this string
         # (after which the resulting character-list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 236 B

This function requires a processor supporting features of Extended Pascal as described by ISO standard 10206, in particular the string capabilities.
Note, the golfed version is restricted to 98 digits.
Furthermore, a character (here the sign) is *always* prepended.

```pascal
type s=string(99);function f(n,b:integer):s;begin
f:=('- +')[ord(n>0)-ord(n<0)+2];n:=abs(n);repeat
f:=('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')[n mod b+1]+f;n:=n div b
until n=0;n:=length(f);f:=f[n]+f[1..n-1]end
```

Ungolf’d, annotated and reasonably good programming style:

```pascal
    const
        { Number of binary digits required to write `maxInt` out. }
        maxIntBinaryLength = trunc(ln(maxInt) / ln(2)) + 1;
        { Known digits for `positionalNotation` function. }
        digit = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' +
                          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        { Characters for negative sign, no sign, and positive sign. }
        sign = '− +';
    
    type
        { For sorting purposes starts with `integer…` prefix. }
        integerNonNegative = 0‥maxInt;
        { A string capable of representing any integer plus a sign. }
        integerString = string(maxIntBinaryLength + 1);
        { Acceptable `base` for `positionalNotation` function. }
        radix = 2‥62;
    
    { Returns −1, 0, or +1 depending on the sign of the argument. }
    function signum(protected n: real): integer;
        begin
            signum ≔ ord(n > 0) − ord(n < 0)
        end;
    
    { Retrieve positional notation of a given integer in a given base. }
    function positionalNotation(
            protected n: integer;
            protected base: radix
        ): integerString;
        { Separate string to work with, and ensure non‑negative number. }
        function position(magnitude: integerNonNegative): integerString;
            begin
                position ≔ '';
                { This is just your run‑of‑the‑mill Horner’s method. }
                repeat
                begin
                    { Prepend a digit. Note, string indices are 1‑based. }
                    position  ≔ digit[magnitude mod base + 1] + position;
                    magnitude ≔ magnitude div base
                end
                until magnitude = 0
            end;
        begin
            { The algorithm is prepending digits, but the sign must be first. }
            positionalNotation ≔ sign[signum(n) + 2] + position(abs(n))
        end
```

[Signum function PPCG challenge](/a/259260/94076) │ [RosettaCode](https://RosettaCode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert#Pascal) │ [FreePascal Wiki](https://wiki.FreePascal.org/Base_converting)