# Print integers in any base up to 36

Tags: code-golf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer to string with given radix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/536/integer-to-string-with-given-radix)

This question is inspired by Pythons builtin `int` function. `int` is used to convert other numbers or strings into integers. If you are converting a string you can provide the additional parameter `base`, that contains the base that your number is represented in within the string:

```
>>> int('137')
137
>>> int('137',base=8)
95
>>> int('ff',base=16)
255
>>> int('1AZ',base=36)
1691
```

Unfortunately Python doesn't provide a function for the reverse case, where you want to convert a number into a string in a specific base.

Your task is to write such a function.

- the function may return the value or print it
- you must provide support for all bases between 2 and 36
- digits to use are `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
- all languages are allowed
- built in functions for this purpose are boring and thus forbidden
- shortest code wins

Comment: "built in functions for this purpose are boring" - and the problem itself isn't?

Comment: huh. i didnt think it was such a bad question :(

Comment: I thought it's a bit boring but it's a good exercise for golf beginners... +1 to even out that unfair -1!

Comment: In fact, it's a trivial variant on some existing questions, most notably http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/536/integer-to-string-with-given-radix,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### APL (25)

```
{(⎕D,⎕A)[1+⍵⊤⍨⍺⍴⍨⌈⍺⍟⍵+1]}
```

The left argument is the base, and the right argument is the number.

i.e.

```
    16{(⎕D,⎕A)[1+⍵⊤⍨⍺⍴⍨⌈⍺⍟⍵+1]}1234
4D2
```

Answer (score 3):

### Befunge, 17x4 = 68 characters

```
1-&00p&>:!#v_:00v
v-10<  ^/g00\%g <
< >:^@_.# #$v#:!`
"_^#`9::$  <<,+"W
```

Online interpreter: http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground

First input is base, second is number.

Similar to other solutions here this does not output anything when the number is 0.  I may look at fixing this at some point.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 68

```
c(n,b,r){char*p=1+&r;for(r=0;n;n/=b)*--p=n%b+48+(n%b>9)*39;puts(p);}
```

testing:

```
main(){
  c(65,2);
  c(100,30);
  c(57005, 16);
}
```

output:

```
1000001
3a
dead
```

issues:

- 0 is printed as empty string.
- potential buffer overflows due to abuse of 'int' as a char array...
- works with Apple clang v4.0 - your milage may vary with other compilers.

Comment: Just to tease you a bit, i've got a working c function in 48 characters, i will release it after i choose a winner :)

Comment: Also, it's architecture specific (depends on endianness of system).

Comment: Furthermore, puts appends a newline, so your outputs are vertical.

Comment: The 48 char version is out now, thanks to Wug, but its far less interesting/dangerous than yours. The code that gcc produces is remarkably safe, since r is the last value on the stack and the stack isnt used after that, all you are overwriting is uninitialized stack space. you could even get rid of the `1+`, so you would ensure there is always a 0 byte at the end of the string. @Wug: he doesn't print character-wise, so the output is fine.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <strike>81</strike> 58 bytes

```
x=lambda n,b:(n/b and x(n/b,b)or'')+chr(48+n%b+39*(n%b>9))
```

Usage:
`x(100,30)` returns `'3a'`, which is 100 in base 30.

Comment: some output characters are not from the required alphabet: `x(30,36)='~'`

Comment: 3a is 100 in base 30 (3*30+10)

Comment: quasimido and @SeanCheshire - both right, a stupid mistake by me (same bug caused both symptoms). Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 92 Bytes

Quite new to code-golf, so probably can do better than this (suggestions would be very welcome!)

```
function b($n,$b){while($n>0){$r=$n%$b;$n=floor($n/$b);$s=($r>9?chr(87+$r):$r).$s;}echo$s;}
```

With (some) whitespaces:

```
function b($n,$b)
{
  while ($n>0)
  {
    $r=$n%$b;
    $n=floor($n/$b);
    $s=($r>9?chr(87+$r):$r).$s;
  }
  echo $s;
}
```

Comment: Next time somebody has to -1 my answer, could you please explain why? I am trying to learn here :) No hard feelings!

Comment: You could probably shorten it by making the function recursive. Remember, you don't need to print the string, returning it is enough.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 48 chars

```
i(n,b){n?i(n/b,b),putchar(n%b+48+(n%b>9)*39):0;}
```

- input of 0 produces empty string

## C, <strike>77</strike> 49 chars, prints `0` for zero

```
I(n,b){putchar(n?i(n/b,b),48+n%b+(n%b>9)*39:48);}
```

[To run, call i for first version, I for second.](http://ideone.com/UhR2E)

Comment: @quazimodo: I got this by hax0ring your computer.  It was hard because you had norton, but you'll never catch me because im behind 7 proxies.

Comment: youre so 1337! But i need just one more char to print zero as `0` :D

Comment: @quasimodo: like this? :D

Comment: more like this: `c(n,b){n/b&&c(n/b,b);putchar((n%b>9)*39+48+n%b);}`. But yours is also nice!

Answer (score 1):

### C# – 85 characters

```cs
string F(int n,int b){var s="";for(;n>0;n/=b)s=(char)(n%b+(n%b>9?87:48))+s;return s;}
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBA, 99

(70 if you take out the function/endfunction lines)

```
Function F(a,b)
F="":q=a:Do:c=q Mod b:F=Chr(c+48-39*(c>9))&F:q=Int(q/b):Loop Until q=0
End Function
```

fixed for case when **a=0**

Answer (score 1):

## Ocaml, 98 or 120

It prints out a leading zero, though. Usage: `16-0xBEEF`

```
let rec(-)b=function|0->"0"|n->b-n/b^String.make 1(Char.chr(n mod b+if n mod b>9 then 55 else 48))
```

Unfortunately a lot of characters are spent on converting to char then to string :/

This one is correct.

```
let rec(-)b=function|0->"0"|n->(if 0=n/b then""else b-n/b)^String.make 1(Char.chr(n mod b+if n mod b>9 then 55 else 48))
```

The strong typing in ocaml is sometimes unfortunate when golfing. Partial application and such somewhat make up for it, though.

Answer (score 1):

### CoffeeScript (<strike>98</strike> 92)

```
z=(i,b)->a=parseInt(i)%b;return''if 1>i;(z i/b,b)+if a>9then String.fromCharCode(a+87)else a
```

The compiled (and readable) javascript for the interested:

```
z = function(i, b) {
  var a;
  a = parseInt(i) % b;
  if (1 > i) {
    return '';
  }
  return (z(i / b, b)) + (a > 9 ? String.fromCharCode(a + 87) : a);
};
```

What can I say? Unnecessary recursion gets me hot.

This could have been far shorter if I knew a shorter way to floor or convert from ASCII in Coffee-/Javascript. Tips would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited** to include "parseInt" to save a couple of characters on "Math.floor" and with some rearranging to reduce the "if ... then ..."s. Unfortunately, I don't think there even is a shorthand if in CoffeeScript ( "... ? ... : ..." doesn't work).

Comment: parseInt() would be 2 char shorter of Math.floor, and I believe would have the same effect

Comment: you don't need Math.floor if you are using String.fromCharCode to print the numbers, also you can probably shorten the code a bit by using shortcut operators instead of ifs.