# Find a numeric coincidence when representing numbers in various bases

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, base-conversion

Recently, when doing some code-golf challenge, I came up with with two solutions, in 69 and 105 bytes. [It's a remarkable coincidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/69_%28number%29), because:

- 69 (decimal) = 105 (octal)
- 69 (hexadecimal) = 105 (decimal)

What other numbers have this property (using different bases)? You should help me answer this question!

Write a program or a subroutine that receives as input 3 numbers (base1, base2, base3, in ascending order), and prints two sequences of digits `d1 d2 d3 ...` and `D1 D2 D3 ...` that reproduce this numerical coincidence for the specified bases.

To make sure the various fine points are covered:

- Evaluate one sequence as a number in base `base1`, and the other sequence in base `base2` -- you must get the same number
- Evaluate one sequence as a number in base `base2`, and the other sequence in base `base3` -- you must get the same number
- Both sequences must have finite length, which is greater than 1
- Separate the sequences of digits with whitespace or in any other unambiguous way
- Output to `stdout` or other similar output device
- All digits must be between 0 and `base-1`; leading zeros are not allowed
- If a digit is greater than 9, use `a` or `A` for 10, `b` for 11, ..., `z` for 35
- You may assume that all bases are different, come in ascending order and are in the range 2...36; are represented in the most natural way for your language
- If there is no answer, your code must signal it in some way (e.g. outputting nothing)
- If there is an answer whose larger number is less than 1679616 (36<sup>4</sup>), your code must find it; otherwise, it may output as if no solution exists
- Code-golf: shortest code wins!

Example input:

```
8, 10, 16
```

Example output:

```
69 105
```

or

```
104 68
```

Or any other solution.

I'll be happy if you provide theoretical insights into this problem (How to determine whether a solution exists? Is there an infinite number of solutions?).

Comment: There can't be infinite number of solutions because the numbers will not have the right lengths, unless log(base1)/log(base2) = log(base2)/log(base3), where there are trivially infinite number of `1000000...` solutions.

Comment: Do we have to provide one solution, or all solutions?

Comment: @Ypnypn Any one solution

Comment: You should better specify what is the meaning of the 2 sequences outputted, and that the numbers in them should be different.

Comment: @rcrmn I hope it's clear now. The numbers in them should be different, but I didn't mention this, because it follows from other conditions (`base1 < base2 < base3`)

Comment: why did the mathematician confuse halloween and christmas, etc. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python 2, 158 bytes

Came a bit too easily, so I might be missing something obvious!

```
s=lambda n,b:(n/b and s(n/b,b)or'')+chr(48+n%b+39*(n%b>9))
def f(a,b,c):
 for n in range(b,36**4):
  x=s(n,a);y=s(n,b)
  if int(x,b)==int(y,c):print x,y;break
```

The base conversion function is lovingly stolen from @ugoren's solution to [Print integers in any base up to 36](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8606/print-integers-in-any-base-up-to-36). The code simply tries all possible values for the smaller number and the rest is fully determined. We start counting from *base2* to ensure both sequences are at least length 2.

```
>>> f(8, 10, 16)
100 64
>>> f(8, 10, 17)
>>> f(16, 20, 24)
20 1c
```